# How to apply multiple filters in asterisk 20.4.0 AMI interface

Tags: regex, asterisk

I just want to filter all event that contains "Event: Hangup and "Channel: PJSIP/ANCONA_UFFICIO" against an event like this:

```
Event: Hangup
Privilege: call,all
Channel: PJSIP/ANCONA_UFFICIO-8f8f88
ChannelState: 6
ChannelStateDesc: Up
CallerIDNum: xxxxxxx
CallerIDName: xxxxxxx
ConnectedLineNum: 235
ConnectedLineName: WASSILIS IT
Language: it
AccountCode:
Context: ext-group
Exten: h
Priority: 1
Uniqueid: 1700241723.5022
Linkedid: 1700241723.5022
Cause: 16
Cause-txt: Normal Clearing
```

So I'm using this regex:

```
Action: Login
Username: user
Secret: mypassword

Action: Filter
ActionID: 998
Operation: Add
Filter: [\s\S]*Event: Hangup\b[\s\S]*Channel: PJSIP\/ANCONA_UFFICIO[\s\S]*
```

and it doesn't works, my ami console doesn't show any events on any kind of hangup, the strange thing is that if I separate the two rules like this, it will work

```
Action: Filter
ActionID: 998
Operation: Add
Filter: [\s\S]*Event: Hangup\b[\s\S]*

Action: Filter
ActionID: 998
Operation: Add
Filter: [\s\S]*Channel: PJSIP\/ANCONA_UFFICIO[\s\S]*
```

but in this way is like an OR logical condition but I need and AND. I tried the above regex in https://regex101.com/r/Bqn3Ce/1 and it's working as expected without any global flag activated. So must be sometghing in how regex works in AMI

Answer (score 0):

Ok the solution is this, probably AMI regex follows an older pattern that doesn't accept [\s\S] and with the dot is considering new lines too.. anyway I tried 1milions combinations and I found the solution is this

```
Filter: Event: Hangup\b.*Channel: PJSIP\/ANCONA_UFFICIO
```